# Contact form with validation and confirmation message box in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I'm developing my first application with Sencha Touch 2 and I'm strongly grounding my code on the [Getting Started tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started) on the official website.
Similarly to the getting started tutorial (I didn't change the code), in app.js when I submit the form I call contact.php:

```
   // Sends an AJAX request with the form data to the url specified above (contact.php).
          // The success callback is called if we get a non-error response from the server
            form.submit({
              success: function() {
            // The callback function is run when the user taps the 'ok' button
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Mail received', 'We will reply soon', function() {
           form.reset(); 
             });
         },
      });
```

However I modified contact.php in order to output a json message just if a condition is satisfied:

```
<?php
if ($_POST[email] != NULL) {
print '{"success": true}';
}
?>
```

Now if the php outputs success:true in JSON format the app.js show an alert message (see code above) "Mail received". Othewise no message will be displayed.

However if I wanted to add to contact.php other possible cases to trigger different messages, how would I implement them in app.js?
For instance, if I modified contact.php with something like:

```
  <?php
            if ($_POST[email] != NULL) {
            print '{"success": true}';
            } else {
    print '{"wrongemail":true"}';
    }
   ?>
```

how would I implement this in app.js so that a different alert (e.g. "your email address is not valid or null") would appear?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a "failure" handler on the form.submit() call:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-submit